# Rsync a folder as root on a rooted android device

Tags: rsync, root, android

I would like to get the content of the folder `/data` of my rooted android device. I tried with `adb`, but because `/data/` is owned by root, I need to first copy the content of `/data` in the extcard, and then use `adb pull`. However when I tried to do that I had some strange thing that happened: lot's of folder were missing after the copy into the sdcard, while if I manually copy one by one everything works fine (if you know why, please tell me!).

So I tried then to use directly `rsync` and the application ssh helper on the android device to synchronize this folder owned by root. But because I need to run it at root, I can't just run a basic

```
rsync -av -e 'ssh -p 2222' root@192.168.1.40:/data /tmp/android_data/
```

Answer (score 0):

To do that, I found this solution: first install on android `ssh helper`, run it, and then run on your computer:

```
rsync -a --rsync-path="su -c rsync" -e 'ssh -p 2222' root@192.168.1.40:/data /tmp/android_data/
```

I'm not sure to understand why it works, because `rsync` is not supposed to be installed on android, but it works... (if anyone knows why it works, please tell me in comments!)

Comment: The rsync flag `-e` specifies to use the ssh protocol, which is why it works.  Rsync can create checksums of remote files over `ssh`, and transfers them using `scp`